# Why does NetBeans always want to exclude this file from SVN commits?

Tags: svn, netbeans

I don't understand this quirky NetBeans issue, every time I go to commit to one branch of our SVN repo, NetBeans always wants to exclude one particular file:

[image: Why netbeans why?]

What can I do to make NetBeans not exclude that file from commit by default? I know I can click the checkbox to include it in *this* commit, but on the next commit it will be excluded again. It's annoyed me to the point I want to fix it now :-)

**EDIT:** Note that the command line works fine:

```
[jnet@Stan ApparelQuote.module]$ svn commit -m "Fixed missing space in message"
Sending        ApparelQuote.module/Contents/Controllers/Module_ApparelQuote.php
Sending        ApparelQuote.module/Contents/htdocs/ApparelOrderingSystem.js
Transmitting file data ..
Committed revision 12288.
```

Comment: possible it is being ignored in your .hgignore

Comment: @Vincent: pretty sure Subversion ignores .hgignore...

Comment: @Shog9 Oops. I did not read the tags. Thanks.

Comment: Nor did you read the question... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the parent directory ('htdocs', above) is being excluded from commits in NetBeans?

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans, right click the file and go to the Subversion menu and see if you have an option toward the bottom that says "Include in Commit". If so, clicking that should include it in the future.

NetBeans allows you to mark files as excluded or included in commits and you may have accidentally marked it as an exclusion from within NetBeans.

Note: The option will be grayed out unless the file has changes, so if the option's grayed out, make a file modification and save it and check again.